# Make room for more buttons in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, popup, uialertview

Can I implement a scroller in my UIAlertView to make place for all the buttons? I have too many buttons to fit in the popup.
Better solutions?

```
- (IBAction)SortButton:(id)sender;

{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"" 
                          message:@""
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Name", @"Country", @"Popularity", @"Fill", @"Freshness", @"Price", @"Alcohol", nil];                                                                                                                                   
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [Action Sheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801), per the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html):

> Generally, use a two-button alert... An alert that contains
>   three or more buttons is significantly more complex than a two-button
>   alert and should be avoided if possible. In fact, if you find that you
>   need to offer people more than two choices, you should consider using
>   an action sheet instead...

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to not have that many buttons.

Barring that you can use a custom alert view from a third party, [this is a good one](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets). Or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is using a popover (If you do it for iPad). Otherwise create a custom view that will look like an alert. And, yes, technically you can addSubview the scroll in alertview, but I do NOT recommend you to do this in order to show a bunch of butons.